# get all objects containing a specific key django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a model called deployed contracts model which looks like following

```
from django.db import models


class DeployedContracts(models.Model):
    house_no = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, default='')
    rent = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    security_deposit = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False)
    house_owner = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    house_tenant = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    deployed_contract_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank='', default='')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeployedContracts, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

where house_owner and house_tenant contains the email of house owner and house tenant and it's serializer looks like following

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from deployedcontracts.models import DeployedContracts


class DeployedContractsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DeployedContracts
        fields = ('house_no', 'rent', 'security_deposit', 'house_owner', 'house_tenant', 'deployed_contract_address')
```

i want to write an API view which a contains a get method which takes an email as parameter and returns all the objects of DeployedContract where either house_owner or house_tenant's email is equal to the email provided in parameter. How can i do that in django?

Comment: See [Complex lookups with Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the filtration part in the `get_queryset` function. And **OR** operation can be implemented using django models [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Now if you call the api with out any parameters, it will return all the DeployedContracts. If you pass any emails, This will return all the filtered result

```
from django.db.models import Q

from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from deployedcontracts.models import DeployedContracts

class DeployedContractsList(APIView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        deployed_contracts = DeployedContracts.objects.all()
        email = self.request.query_params.get('email')
        if email:
            deployed_contracts = deployed_contracts.filter(
                Q(house_owner__iexact=YOURPARAMETER) |
                Q(house_tentant__iexact=YOURPARAMETER)
            )
        return deployed_contracts

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        service_providers = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = DeployedContractsSerializer(service_providers, many=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import a [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) and try this:

`from django.db.models import Q`

```
qs = DeployedContracts.objects.filter(
    Q(house_owner__iexact=YOURPARAMETER) |
    Q(house_tentant__iexact=YOURPARAMETER)
)
```

Read the docs for more.

Answer (score 1):

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.db.models import Q


class DeployedContractsAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email = request.data.get('email', None)
        if email:
            queryset = DeployedContracts.objects.filter(Q(house_owner=email) | Q(house_tentant=email))
            serializer = DeployedContractsSerializer(queryset)
            return Response(data=serializer.data)
        return Response(data={"message": "email parameter not provided"})
```

You can read more about [Django Q expressions here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)